# Supporting new digital cameras Raw files on Linux

Tags: files, camera, thumbnails

This is general question about digital camera raw files. I want to know which software is responsible for rendering the thumbnails.

I have Fedora and have this file /usr/share/thumbnailers/ufraw.thumbnailer that show /usr/bin/ufraw-batch but UFRaw is old last update was in 2015 according to website http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/

so other library must adding support for newest cameras, I have Nikon d750 that works fine but it was released at the end 2014. Does it mean that new cameras are not supported by UFraw and they don't show thumbnails?

I'm asking this because I plan to buy point and shoot camera (Nikon **Coolpix A900**) and it's pretty new. I would like to send the raw file so someone will add support for this files.

Will this camera work with Linux? I mainly use **Gnome** and **Darktable** (for the second one I can send the samples raw files and I will when I get the camera).

So to sum up, my question is **how raw files are handled in Gnome based Linux distribution and how new cameras support are added** (I'm asking mainly about Fedora but general answer may be more useful to future readers)?

I can't find this information, I've found this library https://www.libraw.org/ but it don't say that UFraw is using it.

Comment: How often do camera file formats change? I don't think a new Nikon will be using that different a file format from, say, 4 years ago.

Comment: @muru on Windows when new nikon camera came up it don't work, same as with lightroom it require update for it to work, so I think each camera have different raw files, they can be similar but they don't work out of the box.

Comment: I think they have different profiles - mappings to ensure correct interpretation of the raw files. The formats themselves haven't changed much.

Comment: @jcubic Are you sure Coolpix A900 has RAW support? Quick internet search told me it doesn't.

Comment: @rush I was using compare product site and it shows that it had raw files, but it seems that it not according to Nikon https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/coolpix/a/a900/spec.htm

Comment: @muru: For 'Z 6' and 'Z 7' models Nikon changed raw data packing. There is no reason to believe they will stop at that.

Answer (score 0):

To get thumbnails most of the cases you don't need to render raw data because thumbnails are already embedded into raw files as JPEGs, and for most cameras those thumbnails are large enough. You can extract thumbnails using exiftool or 'libraw/bin/simple_dcraw -e ' Also, please see an example with libraw on https://www.libraw.org/docs/Samples-LibRaw.html